# Why is auto.arima() giving me the Error: "'by' argument is much too small"

Tags: r, arima

I am working on predicting *intra-day* sales for a retailer. We want to know if we can predict sales through the rest of the day, based off sales within that day. I'm working with roughly 3 years of data in a time series, which has given me roughly 26,000 rows of data. 
I've never worked with a time series this large so my approach might be off. Or `auto.arima()` may not have been made to handle data this large.

I've tried limiting my data down to even 300 rows and had marginal success, but have not found anything that works with my larger data set. `auto.arima()` doesn't even have a `by =` argument from what I can find.

```
my_ts <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 
3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 4, 1, 
1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
1, 9, 1, 6, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 
3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 
8, 2, 7, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 7, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 
1, 4, 1, 2, 9, 1, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0, 5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
3, 0, 2, 8, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 3, 
2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 
1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
1, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 7, 5, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 6, 0, 4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0), index = structure(c(1435190400, 
1435194000, 1435197600, 1435201200, 1435204800, 1435208400, 1435212000, 
1435215600, 1435219200, 1435222800, 1435226400, 1435230000, 1435233600, 
1435237200, 1435240800, 1435244400, 1435248000, 1435251600, 1435255200, 
1435258800, 1435262400, 1435266000, 1435269600, 1435273200, 1435276800, 
1435280400, 1435284000, 1435287600, 1435291200, 1435294800, 1435298400, 
1435302000, 1435305600, 1435309200, 1435312800, 1435316400, 1435320000, 
1435323600, 1435327200, 1435330800, 1435334400, 1435338000, 1435341600, 
1435345200, 1435348800, 1435352400, 1435356000, 1435359600, 1435363200, 
1435366800, 1435370400, 1435374000, 1435377600, 1435381200, 1435384800, 
1435388400, 1435392000, 1435395600, 1435399200, 1435402800, 1435406400, 
1435410000, 1435413600, 1435417200, 1435420800, 1435424400, 1435428000, 
1435431600, 1435435200, 1435438800, 1435442400, 1435446000, 1435449600, 
1435453200, 1435456800, 1435460400, 1435464000, 1435467600, 1435471200, 
1435474800, 1435478400, 1435482000, 1435485600, 1435489200, 1435492800, 
1435496400, 1435500000, 1435503600, 1435507200, 1435510800, 1435514400, 
1435518000, 1435521600, 1435525200, 1435528800, 1435532400, 1435536000, 
1435539600, 1435543200, 1435546800, 1435550400, 1435554000, 1435557600, 
1435561200, 1435564800, 1435568400, 1435572000, 1435575600, 1435579200, 
1435582800, 1435586400, 1435590000, 1435593600, 1435597200, 1435600800, 
1435604400, 1435608000, 1435611600, 1435615200, 1435618800, 1435622400, 
1435626000, 1435629600, 1435633200, 1435636800, 1435640400, 1435644000, 
1435647600, 1435651200, 1435654800, 1435658400, 1435662000, 1435665600, 
1435669200, 1435672800, 1435676400, 1435680000, 1435683600, 1435687200, 
1435690800, 1435694400, 1435698000, 1435701600, 1435705200, 1435708800, 
1435712400, 1435716000, 1435719600, 1435723200, 1435726800, 1435730400, 
1435734000, 1435737600, 1435741200, 1435744800, 1435748400, 1435752000, 
1435755600, 1435759200, 1435762800, 1435766400, 1435770000, 1435773600, 
1435777200, 1435780800, 1435784400, 1435788000, 1435791600, 1435795200, 
1435798800, 1435802400, 1435806000, 1435809600, 1435813200, 1435816800, 
1435820400, 1435824000, 1435827600, 1435831200, 1435834800, 1435838400, 
1435842000, 1435845600, 1435849200, 1435852800, 1435856400, 1435860000, 
1435863600, 1435867200, 1435870800, 1435874400, 1435878000, 1435881600, 
1435885200, 1435888800, 1435892400, 1435896000, 1435899600, 1435903200, 
1435906800, 1435910400, 1435914000, 1435917600, 1435921200, 1435924800, 
1435928400, 1435932000, 1435935600, 1435939200, 1435942800, 1435946400, 
1435950000, 1435953600, 1435957200, 1435960800, 1435964400, 1435968000, 
1435971600, 1435975200, 1435978800, 1435982400, 1435986000, 1435989600, 
1435993200, 1435996800, 1436000400, 1436004000, 1436007600, 1436011200, 
1436014800, 1436018400, 1436022000, 1436025600, 1436029200, 1436032800, 
1436036400, 1436040000, 1436043600, 1436047200, 1436050800, 1436054400, 
1436058000, 1436061600, 1436065200, 1436068800, 1436072400, 1436076000, 
1436079600, 1436083200, 1436086800, 1436090400, 1436094000, 1436097600, 
1436101200, 1436104800, 1436108400, 1436112000, 1436115600, 1436119200, 
1436122800, 1436126400, 1436130000, 1436133600, 1436137200, 1436140800, 
1436144400, 1436148000, 1436151600, 1436155200, 1436158800, 1436162400, 
1436166000, 1436169600, 1436173200, 1436176800, 1436180400, 1436184000, 
1436187600, 1436191200, 1436194800, 1436198400, 1436202000, 1436205600, 
1436209200, 1436212800, 1436216400, 1436220000, 1436223600, 1436227200, 
1436230800, 1436234400, 1436238000, 1436241600, 1436245200, 1436248800, 
1436252400, 1436256000, 1436259600, 1436263200, 1436266800, 1436270400, 
1436274000, 1436277600, 1436281200, 1436284800, 1436288400, 1436292000, 
1436295600, 1436299200, 1436302800, 1436306400, 1436310000, 1436313600, 
1436317200, 1436320800, 1436324400, 1436328000, 1436331600, 1436335200, 
1436338800, 1436342400, 1436346000, 1436349600, 1436353200, 1436356800, 
1436360400, 1436364000, 1436367600, 1436371200, 1436374800, 1436378400, 
1436382000, 1436385600, 1436389200, 1436392800, 1436396400, 1436400000, 
1436403600, 1436407200, 1436410800, 1436414400, 1436418000, 1436421600, 
1436425200, 1436428800, 1436432400, 1436436000, 1436439600, 1436443200, 
1436446800, 1436450400, 1436454000, 1436457600, 1436461200, 1436464800, 
1436468400, 1436472000, 1436475600, 1436479200, 1436482800, 1436486400, 
1436490000, 1436493600, 1436497200, 1436500800, 1436504400, 1436508000, 
1436511600, 1436515200, 1436518800, 1436522400, 1436526000, 1436529600, 
1436533200, 1436536800, 1436540400, 1436544000, 1436547600, 1436551200, 
1436554800, 1436558400, 1436562000, 1436565600, 1436569200, 1436572800, 
1436576400, 1436580000, 1436583600, 1436587200, 1436590800, 1436594400, 
1436598000, 1436601600, 1436605200, 1436608800, 1436612400, 1436616000, 
1436619600, 1436623200, 1436626800, 1436630400, 1436634000, 1436637600, 
1436641200, 1436644800, 1436648400, 1436652000, 1436655600, 1436659200, 
1436662800, 1436666400, 1436670000, 1436673600, 1436677200, 1436680800, 
1436684400, 1436688000, 1436691600, 1436695200, 1436698800, 1436702400, 
1436706000, 1436709600, 1436713200, 1436716800, 1436720400, 1436724000, 
1436727600, 1436731200, 1436734800, 1436738400, 1436742000, 1436745600, 
1436749200, 1436752800, 1436756400, 1436760000, 1436763600, 1436767200, 
1436770800, 1436774400, 1436778000, 1436781600, 1436785200, 1436788800, 
1436792400, 1436796000, 1436799600, 1436803200, 1436806800, 1436810400, 
1436814000, 1436817600, 1436821200, 1436824800, 1436828400, 1436832000, 
1436835600, 1436839200, 1436842800, 1436846400, 1436850000, 1436853600, 
1436857200, 1436860800, 1436864400, 1436868000, 1436871600, 1436875200, 
1436878800, 1436882400, 1436886000, 1436889600, 1436893200, 1436896800, 
1436900400, 1436904000, 1436907600, 1436911200, 1436914800, 1436918400, 
1436922000, 1436925600, 1436929200, 1436932800, 1436936400, 1436940000, 
1436943600, 1436947200, 1436950800, 1436954400, 1436958000, 1436961600, 
1436965200, 1436968800, 1436972400, 1436976000, 1436979600, 1436983200, 
1436986800, 1436990400, 1436994000, 1436997600, 1437001200, 1437004800, 
1437008400, 1437012000, 1437015600, 1437019200, 1437022800, 1437026400, 
1437030000, 1437033600, 1437037200, 1437040800, 1437044400, 1437048000, 
1437051600, 1437055200, 1437058800, 1437062400, 1437066000, 1437069600, 
1437073200, 1437076800, 1437080400, 1437084000, 1437087600, 1437091200, 
1437094800, 1437098400, 1437102000, 1437105600, 1437109200, 1437112800, 
1437116400, 1437120000, 1437123600, 1437127200, 1437130800, 1437134400, 
1437138000, 1437141600, 1437145200, 1437148800, 1437152400, 1437156000, 
1437159600, 1437163200, 1437166800, 1437170400, 1437174000, 1437177600, 
1437181200, 1437184800, 1437188400, 1437192000, 1437195600, 1437199200, 
1437202800, 1437206400, 1437210000, 1437213600, 1437217200, 1437220800, 
1437224400, 1437228000, 1437231600, 1437235200, 1437238800, 1437242400, 
1437246000, 1437249600, 1437253200, 1437256800, 1437260400, 1437264000, 
1437267600, 1437271200, 1437274800, 1437278400, 1437282000, 1437285600, 
1437289200, 1437292800, 1437296400, 1437300000, 1437303600, 1437307200, 
1437310800, 1437314400, 1437318000, 1437321600, 1437325200, 1437328800, 
1437332400, 1437336000, 1437339600, 1437343200, 1437346800, 1437350400, 
1437354000, 1437357600, 1437361200, 1437364800, 1437368400, 1437372000, 
1437375600, 1437379200, 1437382800, 1437386400, 1437390000, 1437393600, 
1437397200, 1437400800, 1437404400, 1437408000, 1437411600, 1437415200, 
1437418800, 1437422400, 1437426000, 1437429600, 1437433200, 1437436800, 
1437440400, 1437444000, 1437447600, 1437451200, 1437454800, 1437458400, 
1437462000, 1437465600, 1437469200, 1437472800, 1437476400, 1437480000, 
1437483600, 1437487200, 1437490800, 1437494400, 1437498000, 1437501600, 
1437505200, 1437508800, 1437512400, 1437516000, 1437519600, 1437523200, 
1437526800, 1437530400, 1437534000, 1437537600, 1437541200, 1437544800, 
1437548400, 1437552000, 1437555600, 1437559200, 1437562800, 1437566400, 
1437570000, 1437573600, 1437577200, 1437580800, 1437584400, 1437588000, 
1437591600, 1437595200, 1437598800, 1437602400, 1437606000, 1437609600, 
1437613200, 1437616800, 1437620400, 1437624000, 1437627600, 1437631200, 
1437634800, 1437638400, 1437642000, 1437645600, 1437649200, 1437652800, 
1437656400, 1437660000, 1437663600, 1437667200, 1437670800, 1437674400, 
1437678000, 1437681600, 1437685200, 1437688800, 1437692400, 1437696000, 
1437699600, 1437703200, 1437706800, 1437710400, 1437714000, 1437717600, 
1437721200, 1437724800, 1437728400, 1437732000, 1437735600, 1437739200, 
1437742800, 1437746400, 1437750000, 1437753600, 1437757200, 1437760800, 
1437764400, 1437768000, 1437771600, 1437775200, 1437778800, 1437782400, 
1437786000, 1437789600, 1437793200, 1437796800, 1437800400, 1437804000, 
1437807600, 1437811200, 1437814800, 1437818400, 1437822000, 1437825600, 
1437829200, 1437832800, 1437836400, 1437840000, 1437843600, 1437847200, 
1437850800, 1437854400, 1437858000, 1437861600, 1437865200, 1437868800, 
1437872400, 1437876000, 1437879600, 1437883200, 1437886800, 1437890400, 
1437894000, 1437897600, 1437901200, 1437904800, 1437908400, 1437912000, 
1437915600, 1437919200, 1437922800, 1437926400, 1437930000, 1437933600, 
1437937200, 1437940800, 1437944400, 1437948000, 1437951600, 1437955200, 
1437958800, 1437962400, 1437966000, 1437969600, 1437973200, 1437976800, 
1437980400, 1437984000, 1437987600, 1437991200, 1437994800, 1437998400, 
1438002000, 1438005600, 1438009200, 1438012800, 1438016400, 1438020000, 
1438023600, 1438027200, 1438030800, 1438034400, 1438038000, 1438041600, 
1438045200, 1438048800, 1438052400, 1438056000, 1438059600, 1438063200, 
1438066800, 1438070400, 1438074000, 1438077600, 1438081200, 1438084800, 
1438088400, 1438092000, 1438095600, 1438099200, 1438102800, 1438106400, 
1438110000, 1438113600, 1438117200, 1438120800, 1438124400, 1438128000, 
1438131600, 1438135200, 1438138800, 1438142400, 1438146000, 1438149600, 
1438153200, 1438156800, 1438160400, 1438164000, 1438167600, 1438171200, 
1438174800, 1438178400, 1438182000, 1438185600, 1438189200, 1438192800, 
1438196400, 1438200000, 1438203600, 1438207200, 1438210800, 1438214400, 
1438218000, 1438221600, 1438225200, 1438228800, 1438232400, 1438236000, 
1438239600, 1438243200, 1438246800, 1438250400, 1438254000, 1438257600, 
1438261200, 1438264800, 1438268400, 1438272000, 1438275600, 1438279200, 
1438282800, 1438286400, 1438290000, 1438293600, 1438297200, 1438300800, 
1438304400, 1438308000, 1438311600, 1438315200, 1438318800, 1438322400, 
1438326000, 1438329600, 1438333200, 1438336800, 1438340400, 1438344000, 
1438347600, 1438351200, 1438354800, 1438358400, 1438362000, 1438365600, 
1438369200, 1438372800, 1438376400, 1438380000, 1438383600, 1438387200, 
1438390800, 1438394400, 1438398000, 1438401600, 1438405200, 1438408800, 
1438412400, 1438416000, 1438419600, 1438423200, 1438426800, 1438430400, 
1438434000, 1438437600, 1438441200, 1438444800, 1438448400, 1438452000, 
1438455600, 1438459200, 1438462800, 1438466400, 1438470000, 1438473600, 
1438477200, 1438480800, 1438484400, 1438488000, 1438491600, 1438495200, 
1438498800, 1438502400, 1438506000, 1438509600, 1438513200, 1438516800, 
1438520400, 1438524000, 1438527600, 1438531200, 1438534800, 1438538400, 
1438542000, 1438545600, 1438549200, 1438552800, 1438556400, 1438560000, 
1438563600, 1438567200, 1438570800, 1438574400, 1438578000, 1438581600, 
1438585200, 1438588800, 1438592400, 1438596000, 1438599600, 1438603200, 
1438606800, 1438610400, 1438614000, 1438617600, 1438621200, 1438624800, 
1438628400, 1438632000, 1438635600, 1438639200, 1438642800, 1438646400, 
1438650000, 1438653600, 1438657200, 1438660800, 1438664400, 1438668000, 
1438671600, 1438675200, 1438678800, 1438682400, 1438686000, 1438689600, 
1438693200, 1438696800, 1438700400, 1438704000, 1438707600, 1438711200, 
1438714800, 1438718400, 1438722000, 1438725600, 1438729200, 1438732800, 
1438736400, 1438740000, 1438743600, 1438747200, 1438750800, 1438754400, 
1438758000, 1438761600, 1438765200, 1438768800, 1438772400, 1438776000, 
1438779600, 1438783200, 1438786800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), class = c("zooreg", "zoo"), frequency = 24)

fit1 <-auto.arima(my_ts,seasonal = TRUE)
```

I was hoping to get a model through arima, but I'm only getting the error:

> "Error in seq.default(head(tt, 1), tail(tt, 1), deltat) : 
>     'by' argument is much too small"

Comment: Using the included data set, the exact line of code is
```
 fit1 <-auto.arima(my_ts,seasonal = TRUE)
```
It's in the code above but the reprex is so long it is probably hidden.

Comment: The solution is not clear, but this might be somewhere to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840586/using-rollmedian-function-as-a-input-for-arima-function

Comment: Also, a quick review of the source code for [auto.arima](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/newarima2.R) and [arima](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/arima.R) shows that they both call forms of the `seq()` function internally.